# JQuery animate specific container

Tags: jquery, html, razor, model-view-controller

I am trying to animate an edit panel on a recipe-wrapper which contains information about recipes.

When I click the cog, it shows the edit panel successfully. The problem I am having is, I want to show the edit panel for a "specific" recipe but all the recipe containers have the same layout and class names which is causing all the edit panels to open instead of one specific edit panel on which the cog is pressed.

I know this is happening because I have done this functionality using class names but is there a way to trigger it specifically for only that container on which the cog is clicked rather than all of them? an example of what I have done is as given below :

```
<div class=recipe-container>
    <a class="editors-cog></a>
    <div class="edit-panel"></div>
</div>
...for 1000 recipes same code.

$(".editors-cog").on("click",function(){
     $(".edit-panel").show();
});
```

Thanks,
Vishal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. Try this

```js
$(".editors-cog").on("click",function(){
     $(this).siblings(".edit-panel").show();
});
```